# Importing/uploading files from file share to SP 2010 Doc Lib using CSV

Tags: powershell, import, bulk, csv

Can someone please provide a good link (or if you already have a powershell working) that can import files from file share into SharePoint document library using a cvs flat file. I have about 20 columns of all types (string, multi-string, datetime, managed-metadata, choice, etc.).

I saw few but nothing promising. I am short of time and can't evaluate each and every article I run into when doing a bing search. Please suggest. Not sure if this article (http://www.spjeff.com/2012/02/26/powershell-upload-csv-file-to-list-both-server-and-client-om/) is good for document library.

Comment: We had a similar requirement and wrote our own tool using SCOM (.NET). I don't believe there's a tool out there that allow you to set the metadata (as this requires quite a bit of logic if you want to support all field types with just "string" input)

Answer (score 1):

Just to understand correctly, do you want to use the CSV file to provide metadata for the files that will be imported from the file share?

If so, the approach depicted in the article (SPJeff) will not work. This sample uses a SP list as destination (as opposed to a SP library which is needed to support files).

Look at this article in Code Project (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103503/How-to-upload-download-a-document-in-SharePoint-20); this should give you good pointer on how to use the SP API to upload a document AND set the metadata elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following articles

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/10/bulk-upload-files-to-sharepoint-using.html

http://spbulkdocumentimport.codeplex.com/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link is broken, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)